# How to turn off Lite-server

Tags: node.js, npm, localhost, lite-server

I'm using lite-server ('https://www.npmjs.com/package/lite-server').
After hitting `npm start` it hosts on localhost:/3000 .
If I close CMD where I typed in NPM start it turns off the server.

Is there a way to turn it off through cmd? Some short-cut or a key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the key combination `CTRL + C`. Then type `Y` and `Enter`.

That will terminate any process running in the shell. It’s a convention that works for most shells, not just for CMD.